# C++ library public interface as single header file

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

This is an example of a tuigraphics library I'm working on, what would be the best approach into creating it's public interface accessible via a single header file?

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── Cell.hpp
│   ├── Grid.hpp
│   ├── math.hpp
│   ├── Node.hpp
│   ├── Renderer.hpp
│   ├── shape
│   │   ├── CircleShape.hpp
│   │   ├── RectangleShape.hpp
│   │   └── Shape.hpp
│   └── types.hpp
└── src
    └── Node.cpp
```

I would like to access the library like so:

```cpp
#include <tuigraphics.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    Node node(CircleShape(10), Vector2(10, 10));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have thought about putting a header file `tuigraphics.hpp` including all header files, but I'm not quite sure about it. I have never built a static library, and i would like some advice on how to proceed. Also here the CMake configuration:

```
project(libex)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
add_library(tuigraphics STATIC)

target_include_directories(tuigraphics PRIVATE ./include)

target_sources(tuigraphics PRIVATE src/Node.cpp
                        include/Node.hpp
                        include/types.hpp
                        include/math.hpp
                        include/Cell.hpp
                        include/shape/CircleShape.hpp
                        include/shape/Shape.hpp
                        include/shape/RectangleShape.hpp
                        include/Renderer.hpp)

target_include_directories(tuigraphics PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Comment: `I have thought about putting a header file tuigraphics.hpp including all header files, but I'm not quite sure about it.` ? Do it. `I have never built a static library` For static libraries, you have to have source files. If there are only headers, it's only `INTERFACE` library, there are no sources, there is no library.

Comment: Well, you're right to say the least... Thanks a lot. @KamilCuk

Comment: My recommendation: don't do it, unless you're sure you want to make the use of the library convenient at the cost of compilation times. As for making this a header only library: Think about whether you want to include the logic in `Node.cpp` in every file including `Node.hpp` as inline functions.  Making this a header only lib or not doesn't have anything to do with the decision to provide a single header to include everything or not.